# Failing bash if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement

The if statement doesn't seem to be functioning correctly, no matter the if statement result, the program launches. What have I missed?

```
#!/bin/bash

dtime=($(date |cut -c12-13))
sevenO="19"
redshift=($(gtk-redshift -l -31.9530044:115.8574693))

if ( [[ "$dtime" -gt "$sevenO" ]])
then
    $redshift
fi
```

Comment: Have you checked the values of dtime and seven0 when you run this? The if statement seems fine so I'm guessing your values are not what you are expecting.

Comment: You keep using parentheses. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: For debugging purposes you should use `set -x` as the second line of your bash script. It will verbosely output what your script actually does. You can turn it off with `set +x`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you only want to run `gtk-redshift` if the time is between 8 PM and midnight? If so, the problem is that this notation:

```
$(...)
```

runs the command `...` *immediately*, and evaluates to its output; so this statement:

```
redshift=($(gtk-redshift -l -31.9530044:115.8574693))
```

runs the command `gtk-redshift -l -31.9530044:115.8574693`, and then sets the variable `redshift` to be an array containing the output of that command. (An array because of the surrounding `(...)`. Note that in Bash, parentheses are *not* used for mere grouping. They have actual behaviors — such as, in this case, creating an array — and you shouldn't use them in places where you don't want those behaviors.)

You can simplify your Bash script to just this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$(date +%k)" -ge 20 ]] ; then
    gtk-redshift -l -31.9530044:115.8574693
fi
```

Comment: Note that this will get you into trouble if the hour is 08 or 09 -- you'll get octal errors. Either use `date +%k` or force base-10 with `if (( 10#$(date +%H) >= 20 ))`

Comment: @glennjackman: Whoops, thanks. I used `+%H` because I had intended to just bypass numeric comparison and use `>`, but then I decided I wanted to use `20` instead of `19`, and string-comparison doesn't allow `>=`, so I switched back to numeric comparison, and forgot to switch to `+%k`. Long story short . . . I'll fix it now. Thanks. :-)